# How to apply a method to a parameter in MyBatis

Tags: db2, mybatis, ognl

After reading about [Mapper XMLs](http://www.mybatis.org/core/sqlmap-xml.html) I can't help to wonder how one might go about appling some common transforms to a parameter. For example...

```
<select id="selectPerson" parameterType="String" resultType="hashmap">
  <!-- #{name} should always be upper case and have a trailing % -->
  SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE FIRST_NAME like #{name} 
</select>
```

After reading [this](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/mybatis-like-specific-string-td2001201.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491291/how-can-i-use-like-in-sql-queries-with-mybatis-safely-and-db-agnostic) I can make some observations.

1. Using SQL functions such as `upper` or `concat` or `'||'` or `'+'` to do transforms kills performance in DB2
2. I could always wrap the the mapper or expose the details in the service layer but that seems messy

What I want is to be able to do something like...

```
<select id="selectPerson" parameterType="String" resultType="hashmap">
  <!-- #{name} should always be upper case and have a trailing % -->
  SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE FIRST_NAME like #{name.upperCase() + '%'} 
</select>
```

Is something like this possible or what is the second best solution?

***Update:*** it appears that MyBatis uses OGNL for some expression evaluation. For example, `if` and `${}` expressions use OGNL but `#{}` does NOT appear to unless there is some way to trick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran through the same problem too. But I didn't find any solution for this. So I had to preprocess the `#{name}` parameter from the calling function.

Answer (score 16):

## Bind

MyBatis allows for creating values from method and properties in the context using [`<bind/>`](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#bind).

Bind creates a new variable in the scope of the current statement.  The OGNL statement that binds the value can use the passed in `_parameter` object to compute a new bound value that can then used by MyBatis to construct the prepared statement.

---

## Example

Your example using bind:

```
<select id="selectPerson" parameterType="String" resultType="hashmap">
  <!-- #{name} should always be upper case and have a trailing % -->
  <bind name="nameStartsWith" value="_parameter.getName().upperCase() + '%'"/>
  SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE FIRST_NAME like #{nameStartsWith} 
</select>
```

---

## Source

- [MyBatis Dynamic SQL Documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html)

Comment: bind seems to be available only since mybatis version 3.2

Comment: I got this to work like so: `<bind name="pattern" value="'%' + _parameter + '%'" />...WHERE stuff LIKE #{pattern}`  And for safety, parameter is NOT provided by a user.