# How to use PHP string in mySQL LIKE query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string

I am trying to find the number of rows that match a specific pattern. In this example, all that START with "123":

This is working:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_number LIKE '123%'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

The problem is the LIKE will vary, so I'm trying to define it in the script, then execute the query, but this is NOT working:

```
$prefix = "123";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_number LIKE $prefix.'%'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

How can I get this query to work properly in the second example?

EDIT: I've also tried it without the period (also not working):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_number LIKE $prefix'%'");
```

Comment: John, something that I have found helps me when using variables in strings, is to use the curly braces. `$var1 = "foo"; $var2 = "{$var1} bar"; echo $bar2;` Will output: foo bar and you don't have to worry about concatenation, etc etc. Doesn't work as you may think with single quotes for strings, however.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong; there is no need to place a period inside a double-quoted string. Instead, it should be more like

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_number LIKE '$prefix%'");
```

You can confirm this by printing out the string to see that it turns out identical to the first case.

Of course it's *not a good idea* to simply inject variables into the query string like this because of the danger of SQL injection. At the very least you should manually escape the contents of the variable with `mysql_real_escape_string`, which would make it look perhaps like this:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_number LIKE '%s%%'",
               mysql_real_escape_string($prefix));
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

Note that inside the first argument of `sprintf` the percent sign needs to be doubled to end up appearing once in the result.

Comment: There is a danger of injection if you are using any user-inputted data. There is zero danger for: `$var = "rawr"; ... query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col='{$var}'";` You are controlling your own data on-server.

Comment: @Blake: Obviously, but I feel obliged to say it anyway. Code has a way of being adapted to contexts other than the one it was meant for.

Comment: @Jon, Surely. However, you have to specify that queries can be vulnerable to injections... with user-inputted data. There's a difference between saying "Look at that house" and "Look at that house on fire." :)

Comment: This is incomplete; `LIKE` needs additional escaping. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3683868/1553851) for details.

Answer (score 4):

DO it like

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_number LIKE '$yourPHPVAR%'");
```

Do not forget the `%` at the end