# How to correct Php Query for LIKE data?

Tags: php, mysql-error-1064

I am getting a error in my PHP query. I am attempting to do the below query. However, when I put the the code in PHP. The data is not pulling the "like" data.
The search I want:

```
"SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `ID` like \'NAME%\'";
```

My php code:

```
$TABLE= $_POST['cptCode1'];
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID like'".$searchName."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: give some space `like '".$searchName."'"`

Comment: **mysql_*** functions are depreciated. Use **PDO** Or MySQLi : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php http://in2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID like '".$searchName."%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess a space and `%` missing:

```
like '".$searchName."%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID LIKE '$searchName%'");
```

Or Check here
[how-to-use-php-string-in-mysql-like-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133450/how-to-use-php-string-in-mysql-like-query)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this, it works

Replace

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID like'".$searchName."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

with

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID like '".$searchName."%'") or die(mysql_error());
```