# Do SQL LIKE queries require any special attention when it comes to sanitising data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

In simple scenario, where user input is used to filter data using SQL LIKE, are there any specials characters I should be careful about?

```
$input  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

// Should I strip characters like '%'?

$sth    = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `names` WHERE `name` LIKE :name");
$sth->execute(['name' => $input . '%']);
```

I am referring to anything that could dramatically slow down the query/eat up CPU and thus be used for malicious purposes.

Comment: Why are you using LIKE in the first place in this context?

Comment: Because I am searching for names like "George Thomson" given only "George" and similar cases.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Yeah, it would make sense to strip  `%` and `_`from within the input in that case

Comment: I dont know of a first name containing a %.  There is "50 Cents" I suppose, but his first name is 50, I guess... (you can call me 25)

Answer (score 1):

you need to care about the **$input**, it will contain comma mark or quotation mark

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the characters used for wildcard matching.

See [Escaping MySQL wild cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683746/escaping-mysql-wild-cards) for a good discussion on doing this.