# searching for character % in mysql table with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table with units :

```
insert into table unit ('id', 'name') values ('1', 'mg'), 
('2', 'km'), ('3', '%'), ('4', '%.'), ('5', 'mg/100%'), ('6', 'km/h');
```

now I want to find all units that have a % in name (here : %, %. and mg/100%) :

```
select * from unit where name like  '%\%%';
```

works fine from console or phpmyadmin, but when I try to do it with PDO

```
$st = $db->prepare('select * from unit where name like :n'); 
$st->execute(array('n'=>'%mg%'));
```

is OK, but

```
$st->execute(array('n'=>'%\%%'));
```

give me no results...

how to escape % character in PDO prepare/execute ?

Comment: Double? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683746/escaping-mysql-wild-cards

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `ESCAPE` clause to your query:

```
WHERE name LIKE :n ESCAPE '\';
```

In PHP, you'll have to escape the backslashes, of course:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('... WHERE name LIKE :n ESCAPE \'\\\';');
```