# How to remove potentially bad data from PHP and PDO MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using MySQL like so for executing queries:

```
public function query($query, $params = array(), $format = array()) {

    if ( !is_array( $params ) ) return false;

    $dbh = parent::$dbh;

    if ( empty($dbh) ) return false;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

    if ( !empty($format)) {
        $values = array_values($params);
        foreach ( $format as $key => $bind ) {
            switch ($bind) {
                case '%d':
                    $stmt->bindValue($key + 1, $values[$key], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    break;
                case '%s':
                    $stmt->bindValue($key + 1, $values[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    break;
                default:
                    $stmt->bindValue($key + 1, $values[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    $stmt->execute($params);

    return $stmt;

}
```

How can I safely remove invalid characters from a search that uses LIKE:

For instance:

```
 $filter = "filter's";

 if (isset($filter)) {
    $search_filter = 'content LIKE \'%'.$filter.'%\'';

    $sql = "SELECT $search_filter FROM  messages";

    $stmt = $this->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: you could just do `$search_filter = 'content like '.$dbh->quote("%".$filter."%");`

Comment: @Orangepill I'm afraid you didn't get the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683746/escaping-mysql-wild-cards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @YourCommonSense What am I missing... he looking specifically on how to use a like clause in a prepared statement?

Comment: yes, I did. and the answer is to NOT remove the invalid characters and use proper query building techniques.

Comment: I have to agree, the question is quite vague, but one shouldn't use quote() with prepared statements. I thought at first he is talking on LIKE search meta characters

Comment: @YourCommonSense He's not using prepared statement on the bottom example, that's why I opted for using quote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use PDO::quote

Change the assignment of $search_field

```
$search_filter = 'content like '.$dbh->quote("%".$filter."%");
```

If you want to move to parameterized queries you would do

```
$sql = "select * from messages where content like ?";
$params = "%".$filter."%";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: Using `$dbh->quote()` should be a last resort. Parameterized queries are the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I am following your sophisticated code, but something like this

```
$filter = "filter's";

$params = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages";
if (isset($filter)) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE content LIKE ?';
    $params[] = "%$filter%";
} 
$stmt = $this->query($sql, $params);
```

the idea is to create a query with placeholders dynamically but keep all variable parts go via placeholders only.