# Should I manually escape % when using prepared statement and Where column LIKE '%abc%abc'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

There are some tags in my table that has (%) such as: `%tag` OR `tag%`
I am using PDO prepared statement, my problem here is if I need to escape `%` or leaved it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table where tags like :tags";

$tags = 'tag%';
//or
$tags = 'tags\%';

$sth->prepare($query);
$sth->bindValue(":tags", '%'.$tags.'%');
```

UPDATE:

The column value is `test%test` when I search for `test%test` using: LIKE `%test%test` its ok without escape, but I want to find all tags that contains % so when I used `%%%` without escape it shows all results even if the column not contain `%`

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae24e/6

Comment: Just curious - why don't you try and see?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: if search for `%test%test%` its ok without escape, but when I want to find all tags with `%` I need to use `%\%%` why that? otherwise if using `%%%` shows all results

Comment: Why "why"? this is just how it works. % is a wildcard while \% is a literal %

Comment: @YourCommonSense: then what is different between `LIKE \`%%%\`` and `like \`%test%test%\``

Comment: first one will return every row, while second one - only rows contains two tests

Comment: @YourCommonSense: see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae24e/6

Comment: So? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @JasonOOO: Straight question: _"should I manually escape the `%`'s in LIKEs?"_ Straight answer: _"Yes"_. I don't get how SO can bicker about this... Using `addclashes()` in PHP works a treat for this.

Comment: You should look at the very nice answer from @bobince, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683746/escaping-mysql-wild-cards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the comments, I take it your questions is: 
[what is different between LIKE `%%%` and like `%test%test%`] as well '%\%%'.

While I'm sure you know most of it, I'm going to start from scratch for clarity.

- **'%'** in SQL like clause is a 'wildcard' and it match anything. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp for more information. (If you are familiar with Expression Language, it is similar to a '.*')
- **'\%'** on the other hand escapes that 'wildcard' function, enabling you to match '%' characters in the string. (In expression language it's the same as '\.' allowing you to match dots in the string)

So in your circumstance:

- **'%%%'** means: **[match anything][match anything][matching anything]**, and is the same as '%'
- **'%test%test%'** means: **[anything]test[anything]test[anything]**, and as long as there's two 'test' in the string, it is a match. Matches would include 'testtest', 'asfasdftestasfasftest', 'asfasftesttestasdfsd', 'test%%%%test', '%%%%%test%%%%test%%%%'
- **'%\%%'** means: **[anything]%[anything]**, and as long as the string has a '%' literal it will be a match. Matches include '%%%%%', 'asdfasdf%dsaf', '%dasfa', 'asdfasdf%', 'asdf%%dsaf%%dafa%daf%'

Let me know if this has answered your question.

Answer (score -2):

I would personally do it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabler WHERE tags LIKE :tags";
$sth->prepare($query);
$sth->bindValue(':tags', "%{%tags}%";
```