# mysql like to match complete word or beginning of word on string

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Given a search string I need to select every record where (in the field the search is performed on) there is at least one word that begins with the given text.

For example:

```
'John Doe'
```

Have to be be selected with search strings like:

```
'joh'
'do'
'JOHN doe'
```

Have **not** to be selected with

```
'ohn'
'oe'
```

I need (possibly) to avoid full text search.

What I've found to work is

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE SEARCHFIELD LIKE "' . $searchText . '%"'
                                . 'OR SEARCHFIELD LIKE "% ' . $searchText . '%"'
```

I'm asking if there is a better way to do that.

(for "better way" I mean *better performance* or *same performance but more elegant*)

Also, as the query will be built up with a prepared statement, how should I unescape **LIKE** metacharacters in the search string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated in the question the query

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE SEARCHFIELD LIKE "' . $searchText . '%"'
                                . 'OR SEARCHFIELD LIKE "% ' . $searchText . '%"'
```

works for matching records where the `SEARCHFIELD` contains a word that begins with (or is equal to) `$searchText`

---

Regarding performance I've made a test on my development machine `MBP 2,2 GHz i7 quad core`:

Searching for a word on 4.000 records takes around 40 milliseconds.

Records are normally indexed (no fulltext).

I have few thousands records and the query doesn't run very often so for me is good.
The solution may not be suitable for other contexts.

---

To build a prepared statement with the above query I used the technique described here:

[Escaping MySQL wild cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683746/escaping-mysql-wild-cards)

The resulting code is as follows:

```
function like($s, $e)
{
    return str_replace(array($e, '_', '%'), array($e . $e, $e . '_', $e . '%'), $s);
}

/* ... */

/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
    'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE SEARCHFIELD LIKE ? ESCAPE "=" OR SEARCHFIELD LIKE ? ESCAPE "="'
); 

if( $stmt )
{
    /* escape the text */
    $escSearchText = like( $searchText, "=" );

    /* 'like' parameters */
    $like1 = $escSearchText . "%";
    $like2 = "%" . $escSearchText . "%";

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param( "ss", $like1, $like2 );

/* ... */
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE searchfield LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
```

You don't need the `OR` condition -- if a field matches `search%`, it will also match `%search%`.

Comment: No, that will match with 'oe' or 'ohn' too. I'll edit my question to be clear on that

Comment: `LIKE` can't do word matching, it just matches strings.

Comment: You need to use a `RLIKE` instead of `LIKE` and create a regular expression. The same basic approach still works, you just have to use the regular expression that matches the beginning of a word instead of  the first `%`.