# Searching for multiple terms with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for the most effective way to do a search with select with multiple terms in mysql and php.  A basic select for a single key word in mysql can look like this;

```
select * from <table> where (Message like '%term%' or Subject like '%term%');
```

Works fine for a single term.  For multiple terms, the suggestions that I've seen is that each word that's posted from a form should be sent to an array and the contents should be processed with a For loop.  I'm wondering if there's a way to do it on the mysql side?  My suspicion is that there isn't, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it strictly using MySQL, with lots of calls to MID() and so on, but it would be much more complex than in PHP.  In fact, you would almost certainly need a stored procedure, unless you were certain that the query only involved up to a fixed number of terms (e.g., between 1 and 10 words).

PHP will make this much simpler, and you can also use prepared statements to make things more secure.  See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732237/how-do-i-broaden-the-scope-of-a-mysql-like-query/19733842#19733842).

Comment: Very interesting, Ed.  Yes, for the time being I would like to avoid stored procs and do things as simply as possible.  This looks doable.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Ed, quick question - the link to the discussion you posted mentioned some of the security concerns of setting up a search function.  I've been learning about the issue, the sql injections are one of many concerns.  My question is - in this case where all we're doing is running a search in tables, wouldn't it be enough to just use a read-only mysql account to run the query?  It sounds to me about as bulletproof as it can get.  This isn't something that can be done in every instance, but this situation calls for a read operation, not an update or delete, no?

Comment: Read only will help, but imagine this: `$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE x LIKE '%".$search_term.".%'";`  If `$search_term` happens to be `blah' OR x LIKE '`, the net result will be to return *all* results. Depending on the data, this could expose sensitive information. (Edited to fix typo)

Comment: Hi Ed - I have a query where I am referencing several tables and pulling several specific columns.  When I try to run the query with the subsections, I get "ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION <databasename>.subsection does not exist".  I noticed that in your example, it's pulling all information from a single table.  Is there a good reference I can look at for how to write subsections?

Comment: That error sounds like your query contains the word `subsection` somewhere. You're getting the error because that's not a recognized word/name in MySQL, and it's also not defined in your database.  I'm not sure what you mean by "how to write subsections," but I think you mean subqueries.  Take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html).

Comment: Hey Ed - I think I'm confused by the example you referenced in the linked to above, then.  I thought that, in the example, you're producing an output for MySQL that includes the word "subsection".  It looks like what you're saying is that this is PHP code that will generate the mysql statements in the FOR loop (please correct me if I'm wrong.)  What is the "substr($query, 0, -4)", I'm having trouble following this piece.

Comment: Ah, yes - `subsection` is the name of one of the OP's columns in that example. You should change it to match the name and number of your columns. `substr($query, 0, -4)` strips off the last four characters of the variable `$query`, that is, ` OR ` .

Comment: Oh, I see.  "Subsection", "def", and "exception" are columns for the original poster, then?

Comment: Thank you, Ed.  I got my search to work (and learn something new in the process).  My search needs some tweaking, but I'll get there eventually.  Thanks again.