# grails GORM escape % character

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to query database using GORM, when I pass '%' as value, its returning all the rows in the table. how can I escape % character?

```
def query="from Person as t WHERE  (firstName like :firstName)"
def v ="%"
gSearchMap[ firstName]= "%"+v+"%"
def rows = domain.findAll(query.toString(),gSearchMap,limits)
```

Comment: elaborate your question. What you are describing now is perfectly valid behavior. `select * from person where firstname like '%%%'` gives you all rows in a table which are not null. btw, `gSearchMap[ firstName]= "%"+v+"%"` this is wrong.

Comment: I want to select  only fistname column contains % character. I get the % value from user, what is the best way to escape this character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the documentation of your sql server for that syntax details.

in MySQL you would use the `\` for that:

```
def query="from Person as t WHERE firstName like '%\\%%"
```

see [Escaping MySQL wild cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683746/escaping-mysql-wild-cards)

Comment: thanks, Is the function mysql_real_escape_string like this in grails