# how to treat special characters as regular characters pdo

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo

Im a having a problem with this piece of code, im using a form to pass a value to a search engine, what I want to do is to read special character as regular character, becuase if i type %sam% it reads this as part of the 'query', not like a  regular string(normal character)

it is possible to

```
$search = $_GET['query']; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM mobiles WHERE (`name` LIKE :search) or (`type` LIKE :search)"; 
$query_params = array(':search' => mysql_real_escape_string( $search ));

try
{
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
  die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: "becuase if i type %sam% it reads this as a 'query'" WAT?

Comment: Also: why are you trying to use `mysql_real_escape_string`???

Comment: So you want to be able to use wildcard search from the form instead of on the query itself?

Comment: m_r_e_s() is going to fail unless you connected to mysql via mysql_connect - it will not (and literally can't ever) use the PDO connection to do what it has to. And since you're using placeholders, escaping like that is just going to double-escape the data and prevent matches of text that does normally have sql metachars.

Comment: @PeeHaa I just trying to fin a way to read the % simbol as nomar character not a symbol, I hope it makes sense

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683746/escaping-mysql-wild-cards can be of help

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806912/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-using-php-with-a-like-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use quote from your pdo Connection Object

```
 $db->quote($search ); //Assuming your connection is $db
```

Though % is special in that, it is legal in a string, so you would probably have to escape it manually.

```
$search = str_replace("%", "\%", $search),
```

Comment: Given that **`$search`** is being supplied as a value for a bind variable to a prepared statement, the value of `$search` is not included in the SQL text. So the call to the `quote` is not only unnecessary, it will also add literal quotes to the value. (It's not illegal to do this, just very odd that we'd include literal quotes in the search, very odd to perform a search equivalent to `LIKE '%''foo''%'` rather than just `LIKE '%foo%'`. (This was selected as the answer by OP, but it's a bad answer because the recommendation to use `quote` is way off base.

Answer (score 0):

Some points:

- mysql_real_escape_string has no use whatsoever here. named parameters relieves you from thinking about that
- with mysql you can't use the same named placeholder `:search`, either you make two of em (`:search1`,`:search2`) either you set `ATTRIBUTE_EMULATE_PREPARES=>TRUE` when building PDO
- When working with `LIKE` in PDO you must be sure to pass `%` around the string you submit to the placeholder: `array(':search' => '%' . $search . '%');`