# How to disable % from outputting everything

Tags: php, html, mysql, search

Hey I have an search field where I am searching something from my database, now I saw the problem after testing that if I put "%" in the search field it will output everything that I have ready for searching. Is there a way to disable this?

```
<h3>Search Share Details</h3>
<p>You may search either by company name or issue date</p>

<form name = "search" method = "get">
<input type = "text" name = "share" size = "40" maxlength="50">
<input type = "submit" value = "Search">
</form>
```

**Getting contents connecting to DB, fetching results and printing**

```
function get_contents() {

   if(isset($_GET['share']))
    {
        $conn = db_connect();
        $shares = get_shareSearch($conn);
        db_disconnect($conn);
        $contents = array('shares' => $shares);
        return $contents;
    }
    else
    {
        $conn = db_connect();
        $shares = get_share($conn);
        db_disconnect($conn);
        $contents = array('shares' => $shares);
        return $contents;
    }
}


function print_contents($contents) 
{

    if(count($contents['shares']) == 0)
    {
        echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>alert('Sorry but share is not found! Q_Q');</script>";

    }
    else
    {
    ?>   
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Rate</th>
                <th>Issue Date</th>

            </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($contents['shares'] as $share) 
    {
        print "<tr>";
        $identifier = urlencode($share['SHAREID']);
        print "<td><a href='share-details.php?id={$identifier}'>{$share['COMPANY']}</a></td>";
        print "<td>{$share['RATE']}</td>";

        $issue_date = $share['ISSUE_DATE'];
        $issue_date = $issue_date === NULL ? "&lt; not available &gt;" : $issue_date;
        print "<td>{$issue_date}</td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
        </table>
    <?php
    }
}
//require("shares.php");
require("search.php");
?>
```

**Query itself**

```
function get_shareSearch($conn) { 
$id = "";
if(isset($_GET['share'])){$id = $_GET['share'];}
$statement = db_create_statement($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shares  WHERE(company LIKE '{$id}' OR issue_date LIKE '{$id}')");
$resultset = db_fetch_resultset($statement); 
return $resultset;
```

}

Comment: If I entered `%; DROP TABLE shares` in the search box, chances are I'd delete the entire table ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping MySQL wild cards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683746/escaping-mysql-wild-cards)

Comment: What driver are you using? Use prepared statements if available, if not consider switching to a driver that can use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Escape it**

This refers to putting a character in front of it to denote it's meant to be taken literally:

**Original Statement**

```
SELECT * FROM ikeaTable WHERE chair LIKE '5% off';
```

**Escaped Version**

```
SELECT * FROM ikeaTable WHERE chair LIKE '5\% off' ESCAPE '\';
```

**YOURS**

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shares WHERE(company LIKE '\%{$id}' OR issue_date LIKE '\%{$id}') ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: so basically my query would be like 

`"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shares  WHERE(company LIKE '\%{$id}' OR issue_date LIKE '\%{$id}') ESCAPE '\'"           ?`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Database library you are using, but you certainly need to escape the parameters that you include into the query. If not escaped, MySQL will understand % as a special character that basically means 'match anything'.

I would suggest you read the database library documentation (or the code) to see how to include query parameters into your statement or how to escape them directly.

Comment: I am using My Sql 

so basically my query would be like 

`"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shares  WHERE(company LIKE '\%{$id}' OR issue_date LIKE '\%{$id}') ESCAPE '\'" `         ?

Comment: Maybe try to change the query to "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shares  WHERE company LIKE :share OR issue_date LIKE :share "

and add after in the code  db_bind($statement, ':share', $id);