# Escaping meta characters in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, metacharacters

I was surprised to discover that the MySQL query

```sql
SELECT * WHERE name LIKE "%AFA_";
```

returns rows where `name` is `SAFARI.` To get it to match on the underscore, you have to do:

```sql
SELECT * WHERE name LIKE "%AFA\_";
```

Is there a PHP function that can do this transition or do I have to use `str_replace`?

Comment: I don't understand, you are demonstrating how to select a value based on a pattern using mysql and asking how to replace a string in php... How exactly the both are related to one another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683746/escaping-mysql-wild-cards

Comment: If you want ``LIKE`` to match a literal underscore, you must escape it with ``\``, e.g. ``SELECT * WHERE name LIKE "%AFA\_";``. You can also specify a custom escape character: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has no knowledge of MySQL `LIKE` wildcards, nor should it.

It does, however, have a way to escape things in strings if you want, and that *is* `str_replace`.

Replace instances of `_` with `\_`, or whatever you like.

Ultimately this question has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: OK.  I thought there might be a function like `addslashes` that would take care of this task.

Comment: @ScottCWilson There is. `str_replace`.